# PHP Convert a dec to a bit array with a predefined length

Tags: php, arrays, byte, bit

I'm getting confused on how to do a simple thing, perhaps someone can help me.

At one point of my code I convert a bit array with 10 alarms (0 or 1) to a decimal and save it.
At another point I load the decimal and want to convert it back to a bit array.

This works however the bit array should be always have a length of 10 even if the decimal length is not 10 bites.

See my code:

```
// Convert array to dec:
$alarms = array(0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0);
$str = implode("", $alarms);
$dec = bindec($str);

// Convert back to bit array:
$bin = decbin($dec);

echo $bin;
```

The result of this code is:

`10001000`

But should be:

`0010001000`

Thanks!

Comment: Bits are spelled right-to-left, and as such any leading zeroes have no meaning. If you need padding of sorts, you can just add it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an idea of how you might implement this.

```
<?php

// Input array of bits
$inBits = [0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0];
// Convert to decimal value
$value = bindec(implode('', $inBits));
// Convert back to string of 0/1, adding padding as needed.
$outBitStr = str_pad(decbin($value), count($inBits), '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

var_dump(implode('', $inBits) === $outBitStr); // TRUE
```